# How to get an array of IDs as strings instead of object with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, object, mongoose

I am trying to get a list of all ids from a database but I am getting a result that I don't want. I want the result to be an array.
There reason why I want it to be a list is that I want to use it in another query where the condition will work with the data of those ids, maybe there is a way to do that with the result I am getting but I don't know how to do it as well. But if I can get it as an array, I will be able to solve it.

Here is how I am doing it

```
const ids = await Db.find({accountStatus: "active"}).distinct('_id')
```

result

```
[
  new ObjectId("6259e7cb9604555d50939cff"),
  new ObjectId("6259f9502349309b80f215be"),
  new ObjectId("625a7619a4eb4fc6fc3e1507"),
  new ObjectId("625bb731a4eb4fc6fc3e1587"),
  new ObjectId("625bf74c13a4ee9f4ae9d61d"),
  new ObjectId("625c897f363d7af93a6fdd3b"),
  new ObjectId("625d2ef668610464781a34a3")
]
```

desired result

```
[
  "6259e7cb9604555d50939cff",
  "6259f9502349309b80f215be",
  "625a7619a4eb4fc6fc3e1507",
  "625bb731a4eb4fc6fc3e1587",
  "625bf74c13a4ee9f4ae9d61d",
  "625c897f363d7af93a6fdd3b",
  "625d2ef668610464781a34a3"
]
```

Let me know how I can get the result in an array format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a pure MongoDB query solution you can do it like this:

```
Db.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    accountStatus: "active"
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: {
      $toString: "$_id"
    }
  }
}])
```

All `ObjectIds` are converted to strings. I kept out the `distinct` operator since Ids must be unique anyways so there is no point in adding this.

Otherwise you can just map over your result and transform the ObjectIds:

```
const ids = (await Db.find({accountStatus: "active"}).distinct('_id'))
  .map((id) => id.toString())
```

Comment: I am accessing the data with mongoose, I don't think that code will work. thanks

Comment: @Egidius it does work. Just try it out. You can use `aggregate` with Mongoose the same way as with the normal MongoDB driver

Comment: I added another possible solution where you just transform all ObjectIds

Comment: S Here is the error I am getting:
1 option:

 unhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Mongoose 5.x disallows passing a spread of operators to `Model.aggregate()`. Instead of `Model.aggregate({ $match }, { $skip })`, do `Model.aggregate([{ $match }, { $skip }])`


2 option:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Db.find(...).distinct(...).map is not a function

Comment: my fault. I edited both options to fix the errors

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example provided, there are multiple ways of getting to your desired result. I will proceed to enunciate two of them, one using a callback function and the other one using a Promise.

**Method 1**

```
const ids = await Db.find({accountStatus: "active"}).distinct('_id', 
 function(error, ids) {
    // ids is an array of all ObjectIds
    let strArr = []; // Initialize empty array
    // Iterate through ids
    for (let id of ids){
       // Push each id into strArr
       // Id is formatted as a String by using ObjectId's str attribute 
       strArr.push(id.str);
    }
    // Return resulting array
    return strArr;
});
```

**Method 2**

```
// Storing the db call as a Promise
const dbPromise = await Db.find({accountStatus:"active"}).distinct('_id');
// Solving the Promise (can be solved later in the code)
const ids = dbPromise.then(ids => {
   // Same logic as in Method 1
   let strArr = [];
   for (let id of ids){
      strArr.push(id.str);
   }
   return strArr;
};
```

Useful readings:

- [Model.find() documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)
- [db.collection.distinct() documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)
- [ObjectId documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

Comment: Thanks, @Go_dot! I have upvoted your answer. Glad to be your first up-voter ;)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote @Egidius <3 ! Even though Tobias' answer contains a much cleaner solution, I hope mine offered an interesting further reading. Wish u the best !